# How to distinguish active and selected item in Gtk IconView?

Tags: python, gtk

I have a Gtk IconView. Actually, selected items are draw with a different background color (this is the normal behavior). However, I'd like to be able to distinguish between "selected" and "active" items, by using a different background color for the "active" item. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to change something like this, you probably should use a theme.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a theme? Check the panel.rc file and look for **bg[ACTIVE]**. Change that value and the button should change colour

Comment: No, I'm not using theme. I rely on system default theme. However, I'm talking about an IconView, there are no buttons there.